# How to have loading animation script run on every state change in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loading, loading-animation

I am using the following script to show loading animation in my application.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    $scope.state = document.readyState
    if ($scope.state == 'interactive') {
        document.getElementById('contents').style.visibility="hidden";
    } else if ($scope.state == 'complete') {
        $timeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('interactive');
            document.getElementById('load').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('contents').style.visibility="visible";
        },1000);
    }
});
```

This works fine when page loads for the first time. How do I execute it every time state changes, as in some state there is new data being fetched.

I tried calling this script in

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    console.log('State Change');
});
```

but then the application is loading infinitely and in turn never stops loading.

Comment: Have you already tried with $stateChangeStart?

Comment: no I tried with $stateChangeSuccess, I replaced it with  $stateChangeStart, but not working

Comment: Could you try with $stateChangeStart please?

Comment: not working, updated my earlier comment

Comment: Where is the code from $stateChangeSuccess? Could you try changing $scope by $rootScope and adding the code in your app.run (if you don't have it already)?

Comment: try `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(ev, fromState, fromParams, toState, toParams){...});` in `app.run(function($rootScope){...});`